# How to parse two data list from one PagingData Source in Android Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

This is My ViewModle Class

```
            @HiltViewModel
        class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
            private val movieRepository: MovieRepository,
            private val favMovieRepository: FavMovieRepository
        ) : ViewModel() {
        ...
     private var _movieState = mutableStateOf(false)
        val movieState = _movieState
         val nowPlayingMovies: Flow<PagingData<Movie>> = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 10)) {
                MoviePagingSource(movieRepository)
            }.flow
        
            val popularMovies: Flow<PagingData<Movie>> = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 10)) {
                MoviePagingSource(movieRepository)
            }.flow
        ...
 fun setListToPopular(){
        _movieState.value = true
    }
        }
```

PagingSource file is here

class MoviePagingSource(
private val movieRepository: MovieRepository
) : PagingSource<Int , Movie>() {

```
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Movie> {
    return try {
        val nextPage = params.key ?: 1
        val nowPlayingMovieResponse = movieRepository.getNowPlayingMovies(nextPage)
        val popularMovieResponse = movieRepository.getPopularMovies(nextPage)
        LoadResult.Page(
            data = nowPlayingMovieResponse.results,
            prevKey = if (nextPage == 1) null else nextPage - 1,
            nextKey = nowPlayingMovieResponse.page.plus(1)
        )
        LoadResult.Page(
            data = popularMovieResponse.results,
            prevKey = if (nextPage == 1) null else nextPage - 1,
            nextKey = popularMovieResponse.page.plus(1)
        )

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    }
}

...
```

}

Here I define two LoadResult one for NowPlaying other for popluar movies.

I want to get the follwing result as expected Below.
[image: Screenshot]

Here whenever i choose one result should be in my favour for that i have my Home screen.

@Composable
fun MovieListView(viewModel: MainViewModel) {

```
val lazyMovieItems = viewModel.nowPlayingMovies.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
val lazyPopularMovieItems = viewModel.popularMovies.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

val movieItems = if (!viewModel.movieState.value) lazyMovieItems else lazyPopularMovieItems


LazyColumn {
    item {
        Row(... ) {
        PopularityDropDown(){
            viewModel.setListToPopular()
        }
        } }
    items(movieItems) { item ->

        MovieCard(movie = item!!) {
            ...
                )

            }else Log.d(TAG, "MovieListView: ${item.original_title} with id ${item.id} It is Not favorite ")
        }


    }
    movieItems.apply {
        ...
}
}
```

What should be the way for fetching data from PagingSource ? and please suggest better way for handling NowPlaying and popular movie.

Comment: The problem is resolved :) but still i like to see others approach.

Comment: can u share the approach?

Comment: at present i forgot what i did, but may be you can check my repo for finding approch. May that help https://github.com/ashgautamDev/NowPlaying-App